# how to update flag(database column) in oracle forms 10g

Tags: oracleforms

I need a code on , flag update , i have flag (database column), after the program is successfully then flag need to Update as N, i need add code Button

checked Y
 unchecked N

can you please help me?

Comment: Check out the `update` statement: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10008.htm#SQLRF01708

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is 2 options for updating the database field:

- POST-FORMS-COMMIT trigger is fired just after the DML commands (Insert,..) so you can write the code there and update the database flag
- At the database level you can create a trigger that contain the column change after update.

Comment: I need to update flag as N where there flag is Y means it is sucesfully processed, Otherwise, the Flag Y data also processing, so i need Update Flag As N(these are the succeded Flag's), Bcz i have a single Record Block , I have condition to insert the data into the Code flag=Y records only insert

Comment: Rajesh123 the flag is a database column, so you can on KEY-COMMIT trigger: select from the database the flag value and then check if this value is Y (If flag=Y ..) then COMMIT and update the flag to N.